# magento phantom sticky nav style appears from nowhere

Tags: magento-1.9

On my site for some reason I keep getting a margin-top:-40px; style applied to my sticky-nav. This takes it off the screen when you scroll, and when you do return to the top lays it on-top of my header. I can not find out where this style is coming from. it is applied to the element, so I can't find it on a stylesheet. I am at a loss for where this is coming from.

https://www.popstops.com

magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I had an extension overwritting Jquery causing this issue